# Finding unused methods in .net environment

Tags: .net, static-code-analysis

Is it possible to find all the unused method in a solution?

I.e.

Private method not called inside the class or method which are called from methods which are not called

Comment: It must be possible because Resharper seems to be able to do it.

Comment: @Revious: I'm not sure if that's how Resharper does it, but for private methods I guess you can just look for it's name in the file (or more in case of a partial class). If you can't find it except in the declaration, the method is obviously unused. Note that this is not a 100% guarantee since everything can be called using reflection.

Comment: I remember seeing a Microsoft video of test and it would show any code the test did not hit but I cannot find the reference.   Search test.

Comment: @Revious ReSharper likely does it using the same mechanism by which it finds usages. I'm not sure, but I think it has limited support for detecting dynamic uses, but I'm not sure if that also covers Reflection. It isn't always safe to remove a method that *looks* like it isn't used ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use static code analysis for this task if you have access to a Visual Studio Pro (or above). The relevant rule is [CA1811](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182264.aspx). Please note that this method gives you a good starting point but might report false positives, so you should be cautious when you remove methods.

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264939.aspx) for an overview of static code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use NDepend following this article:

http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Methods.html